# How to deploy a Azure VM with few file existing already using ARM template?

Tags: azure, azure-vm-scale-set, azure-vm-templates

I want to deploy a linux vm using ARM template with few files already downloaded into it in some specific directory, how to do that?
Those files can be fetched either from my file system or from github.

Comment: Aside from deploying a VM with a custom image, you'd have to have some type of startup operation after deploying.

Comment: Thanks @DavidMakogon , you mean to say creating a VM with custom image will have all data files other than OS and installed softwares? Also, can you enlighten what startup operation needs to be done post deployment?

Answer (score 1):

You could use something like DSC to achieve this. You could deploy the ARM template and set to apply a DSC configuration much like in [this link](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/brian_farnhill/2015/03/15/using-dsc-to-download-from-azure-file-storage-to-an-azure-vm/).

The file you want downloaded needs to sit in an Azure storage account and set the destination path in the DSC configuration.